# Passing nullable types to SQL Server CLR function - 2008 only

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, clr

Is it only SQL Server 2008 that allows you to pass a nullable type into a CLR function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup :-( :-(......................

Comment: And even that doesn't seem to work.  Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate fails to deploy functions that use nullable types, with a useless error suggesting "The method "MyMethodName" is marked as a table-valued function and must define a table definition in the SqlFunction attribute".  It's not marked as a table-valued function at all, so I don't know why it's saying that.  The attribute is "SqlFunction" and the only parameter is a "DateTime?" and so is the return type.